# Binding DataGridView with IList<T>, edit and then save only the changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I have the following service class:

```cs
public class MyService 
{
    List<MyModel> GetData() { .... }
    void Save(List<MyModel> changedRows) { .... }
}
```

Is it possible to bind the data source of the DataGridView to the list returned by `myService.GetDate()`; and then user edit in the DataGridView and click a "SaveAll" button to commit all the changes by calling the function `myService.Save(???)`?

Is it possible to get a list of the changed rows and pass it to `myService.Save(list)`?

This seems a common issue but I cannot find much information. Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: DataTable has the functions to catch the changes. Maybe building another layer converting the `List<MyModel>` into DataTable and then convert it back to `List<MyModel>` for `myService.Save`?

Answer (score 1):

Couple options I can think of:

1) You can wrap the `MyModel` class inside a `MyModelView` class that includes a `MyModel` property and a `Status` enum property (inserted, updated, deleted). When you get the `List<MyModel>`, you can create and fill a `List<MyModelView>` and bind that new list to the datagridview. Any time the user edits a row, you update the `Status` property according to the user action (inserted, updated, deleted). Note that this also requires some extra work for [filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx) out the deleted rows, as you probably don't want the deleted rows to be displayed.

2) You'd bind the `List<MyModel>` directly to the datagridview, but have a seperate `List<MyModelView>` that only includes changed rows. Any time there is a change, you'd track the change in this separate list.